# Cannot copy file because it "is being used by another process" despite command line tools copying the file just fine

Tags: c#, macos, filesystems

On macOS, the following C# code throws the following exception (both on netcoreapp3.1 and net6.0)

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.Copy("/Users/jbickle/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History", "/Users/jbickle/Downloads");
        }
    }
}
```

```
Error copying the file: The process cannot access the file '/Users/jbickle/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History' because it is being used by another process.
```

While the output of `lsof` reveals that the file *is* being used by Google Chrome, this exception is quite odd because outside the .NET environment I am able to copy the file just fine (such as using `cp`).

Why is it that my C# code throws this exception despite my ability to copy the file using other methods? Is there any way around it?

Comment: Seems like File.Copy() is applying Windows semantics - which could be by design to have consistent behavior. But a quick look at the docs didn't turn up anything.